# Communication between siblings components

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components: **first** component and **second** component, which themselves are children of component **parent**, and the first component has a child **first_child**. Now I want to update(show/hide) the second component based on whether an element in **first_child** has been clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can used below mentioned code

```
var FirstChild=React.createClass({
  render:function()
  {
    return(
      <div>
      <h1>First Component Child</h1>
       <button onClick={this.props.Click} >Click</button>
      </div>

      )
  }
});
var First=React.createClass({
  render:function()
  {
    return(
      <div>
      <h1>First Component</h1>
      <FirstChild Click={this.props.click}/>
      </div>

      )
  }
});
var Second=React.createClass({
  render:function()
  {
    return(
      <div>

       <h1>Second Component</h1>
       {this.props.isShow?<h1>Show</h1>:null}
      </div>

      )
  }
});

var ParentComponent=React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function()
  {
    return{
      isShow:false
    }
  },
  ClickEvent:function()
  {
    alert('clicked');
    this.setState({isShow:true});
  },
  render:function()
  {
    return(
      <div>
      <First click={this.ClickEvent} />
      <Second isShow={this.state.isShow}/>
      </div>

      )
  }
});
React.render(
  <ParentComponent />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pt1Midvtt9eiWS8unAQv?p=preview)

Comment: Yes this should work. But maybe I have not been clear enough:

One element is **NavBar**, and the other one is **List**, and the list contains a component **ListItem** which generates a **ListItem** for every item in the database. Now I have given all these items a checkbox, and I would like to use this checkbox as a toggle for an icon on the right side of the NavBar. If no checkbox is ticked => hide the iconInNavbar; else show it.